# can i download a file from url in java without an internet connection?

Tags: java, download, cron

I want to download a xml file from url  in java.But the condition is if i dont have an internet connection then how should i do that ?

```
ArrayList<String> urls =new ArrayList<String>();
urls.add("http://www.un.org/sc/committees/1267/1267.xml");
urls.add("http://www.un.org/sc/committees/1988/1988.xml");  
urls.add("http://www.un.org/sc/committees/consolidated.xml");  
urls.add("http://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/sdn.xml");  

Iterator itr=urls.iterator();  

while(itr.hasNext()) {
    String url=(String)itr.next();
    URL file_url = new URL(url);
    logger.info("Url names :"+file_url);
    InputStream stream = file_url.openStream(); 
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    documentBuilder.parse(stream);
}

String str = getJcmsPropertyLoader(context).getUploadXmlPath();
String file_name= "";
File folder = new File(str);
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
for (File file : listOfFiles) {
    if (file.isFile()) {
        file_name = file.getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am writting this code for a cron job =. that run daily and will download file from url. But how to do this if dont have an internet connection ?

Comment: Maybe smoke signals?

Comment: How *would* one download a file that *can't* - by problem precondition - be accessed?

Comment: is there any proxy setting or some way ? Hey Elliott can you explain something more on that ?

Comment: *If* you get an exception while retrieving the URL, then load the data from a file on the file system instead. Bonus points if you update the file every time that you do successfully retrieve the URL from the Internet. Voila, you have a built a simple cache infrastructure.

Comment: @ Erwin : using caches kind of thing for this i think its good. thanks for your answer erwin.